# Getting process id of background process in Perl

Tags: perl

The following bash script works well

```
#! /bin/bash
sleep 2 & echo $!
```

If I try to do this in Perl:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $pid=qx{bash -c 'sleep 2 & echo $! '};
print "$pid\n";
```

it does not return immediately, and it also gives empty output for `$pid`.

Comment: Remember that `qx{}` interpolates like double-quotes, so you'd need to backslash that `$!` to get the pid to print.  It'll still pause for two seconds, because `qx{}` is waiting for all child output to complete, and the _sleep_ shares the same output as _bash_.

Comment: @pilcrow Thanks! This is what I observed too after reading your comment to `mob` below (without reading the above comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $pid = fork;
if ($pid == 0) {
    exec("sleep 2");
}
print "$pid\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well! (It would be nice to know why the `qx` did not work though..)

Comment: `qx` doesn't work because once the shell sees the `&` character, it dissociates itself from the parent process's I/O streams and sends output to the controlling tty instead (which probably doesn't exist)

Comment: So the only way to get the process id with `qx` or `system()` is to write it to a file, which can be later read by the Perl script?

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, All mob said is you can't use `bash`'s `&`. He's even given the basis of a program that would work in `qx`.

Comment: @mob, no I/O streams/controlling ttys here.  The child shell is still sending output to write-end of the pipe which perl created to serve as the child's stdout.  There's no pid printed because `qx{}` interpolates the `$!`, which isn't set, so the _echo_ is invoked with no arguments.  The OP's script prints "\n\n", with the first "\n" having been read off the pipe from the _echo_.

Comment: @pilcrow Yes, you are right: adding a slash in front of `$!` gives the `PID` but still, the command does not return immediately (as it does in the pure Bash script.. )

Comment: It works if I add `> /dev/null` behind the `sleep` command: `qx{bash -c 'sleep 2 >/dev/null & echo \$! '};` This returns immediately :)